# Meter un resultado dentro de una lista

Tags: r

Quiero hacer lo siguiente con un bucle:

```
ana_1 = data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
               col2=c("rojo","verde","amarillo","amarillo 23","pepe","marta","lento"),
               col3=c(150,250,50,100,300,125,200))

ana_2 = data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
               col2=c("rojo","verde","amarillo","amarillo 23","pepe","marta","lento"),
               col3=c(150,250,50,100,300,125,200))

ana_3 = data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
               col2=c("rojo","verde","amarillo","amarillo 23","pepe","marta","lento"),
               col3=c(150,250,50,100,300,125,200))

pepe_1 = data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
               col2=c("rojo","verde","amarillo","amarillo 23","pepe","marta","lento"),
               col3=c(1500,2500,500,1000,3000,1025,2000))

pepe_2 = data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
               col2=c("rojo","verde","amarillo","amarillo 23","pepe","marta","lento"),
               col3=c(150,250,50,100,300,125,200))

pepe_3 = data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
               col2=c("rojo","verde","amarillo","amarillo 23","pepe","marta","lento"),
               col3=c(150,250,50,100,300,125,200))


resultado <- list()
resultado[["pepe"]] <- pepe_1$col3 + pepe_2$col3 + pepe_3$col3
resultado[["ana"]] <-  ana_1$col3 + ana_2$col3 + ana_3$col3
```

Sumar la col3 de "ana" y meterla en una lista y lo propio con "pepe".

Lo mismo con un bucle, pero no consigo meter el resultado en la lista.

```
resultado <- list()

sumaprueba <- function(nombre){

    df1 <- get(paste0(nombre, "_1"))
    df2 <- get(paste0(nombre, "_2"))
    df3 <- get(paste0(nombre, "_3"))

    resultado[[nombre]] <- df1$col3 + df2$col3 + df3$col3
}

nombres <- c("pepe","ana")
for( i in nombres)
sumaprueba(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema con lo que estás intentando es esto:

```
resultado[[nombre]] <- df1$col3 + df2$col3 + df3$col3
```

Lo que ocurre es que dentro de la función, `resultado[[nombre]]` se considera una variable "privada", cuando, entiendo que lo que buscas es acceder al variable externa a la función o global. Para esto simplemente debes usar el operador `<<-` que le indica a R que busque la variable por fuera del entorno de la función.

```
resultado[[nombre]] <<- df1$col3 + df2$col3 + df3$col3
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola utiliza el bucle de esta manera, debería funcionar

```
resultado <- list()

sumaprueba <- function(nombre){
  df1 <- get(paste0(nombre, "_1"))
  df2 <- get(paste0(nombre, "_2"))
  df3 <- get(paste0(nombre, "_3"))
  return( df1$col3 + df2$col3 + df3$col3)
}

nombres <- c("pepe","ana")

for(i in nombres){resultado[[i]] <- sumaprueba(i)}

resultado
```